# view flv video by servletvideo java

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

When I try to view a video in the jwplayer from a file in the webcontent directory it shows up and I can play it, but when I read the **same** file from a database and respond with an flv via servlet it doesn't show up. Can any one help me?

In Html file :

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/ThoughRecord18-8/jwplayer.js'></script>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': '/ThoughRecord18-8/player.swf',
    'file': '/ThoughRecord18-8/videoss?videoId=1',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '470',
    'height': '320'
  });
</script>
```

and the servlet is

```
String videoId = request.getParameter("videoId");
        if (videoId != null || !videoId.equals("")) {
            VideoDao dao = new VideoDao();
            Video video = dao.getVideo(videoId);
            Blob blob = video.getVideoBlob();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            InputStream in = null;
            int len;
            try {
                len = (int) blob.length();
                byte[] rb = new byte[len];
                InputStream readImg = blob.getBinaryStream();
                int index = readImg.read(rb, 0, len);
```

...

```
            response.reset();
            response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            response.setContentType("video/x-flv");
            response.setContentLength(rb.length);
             response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=file.flv");
            byte[] content = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(rb));
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            while (is.read(content) != -1) {
                os.write(content);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();**
```

Comment: What happens if you call the servlet directly from the Location bar in your browser bypassing JWPlayer?

Comment: @Mike - I'm not quite sure where you moved "In Html file:" to makes sense - it's clearly servlet code too, whereas it was previously preceding what is clearly HTML.

Comment: actually when i edited it it was the last line of the question which didn't make sense, so i moved it up a block but you're right that's still not right.

Comment: when i call it from Location bar in your browser it asked me to open or save the flv video, but The problem is how can play the flv video in JWPlayer, The flv file is the same as file in the database, it works when i enter in html file the following  file': '/ThoughRecord18-8/file.flv', but when i call the servlet file': '/ThoughRecord18-8/videoss?videoId=1', it doesn't work is there any soultion for this problem

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a java issue, JW Player only supports HTTP Psuedo Streaming and RTMP Streaming.  They're both their own protocols - you can't just stream the pure content at it.  Take a look at this page: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12534/video-delivery-http-pseudo-streaming, and this page: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12535/video-delivery-rtmp-streaming for info on how JW Player does streaming.

If you don't want the user to have to wait to get all of the content, you'll need to go with one of those streaming mechanisms.  If that's not an issue, you could consider changing your servlet to write the file somewhere in your webcontent directory and then do a redirect to the file or something, but I don't think writing to the response stream like that is going to do the trick.