# play video from servlet outputstream using jwplayer in html

Tags: java, spring, jwplayer, fileoutputstream

After browsing a lot and wasting much time i managed to setup one player that is JWPlayer now this player is able to play the files whose location is in context path something like "video/test.flv". I gave the url of servlet which writes to the response using the outputstream. But jwplayer is not able to play the streamed file. Now i am struck and not able to find a solution for this. Then i found this question which is related to my problem. [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448332/view-flv-video-by-servletvideo-java)

now in the answer someone said that its not possible, so what is the workaround is this impossible? please help me out, wanna sleep.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok guys i got it working, till now its ok, dont know about future. :) my jwplayer6 setup is like this

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
                        file: id,  //dynamic url
                        type: 'flv',
                        image: ""
                    });
```

this may help others.

Thanks